# Wrong symbol defined in shared library with 'using namespace'

Tags: c++, linker

I'm experiencing different symbols being defined in a shared library depending on whether or not the `using` directive is used. I would like to know what I am doing wrong/why the approach does not work.

For this example, I am creating a shared library `libutil.so` from the source file `util.cpp` which includes a header `util.hpp`. The program that links against `libutil.so` is defined in `prog.cpp`.

```cpp
// util.h
#pragma once
namespace util {
int func();
}

// util.cpp
#include "util.hpp"

using namespace util; // This is the directive in question
int func() { return 42; }
```

```cpp
// prog.cpp
#include "util.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << util::func() << std::endl;
}
```

Here is how I compile and link everything (on gcc-7.3.0)

```
g++ -g -std=c++14 -fPIC -o util.o -c util.cpp
g++ -g -std=c++14 -shared -o libutil.so util.o 
g++ -g -std=c++14 -o prog prog.cpp -L. -lutil
```

The last line of which results in this error

```
/tmp/ccwaFRtS.o: In function `main':                                  
/home/wtf/prog.cpp:5: undefined reference to `util::func()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Changing `util.cpp` to this, however, fixes the error:

```cpp
namespace util {
int func() { return 42; }               
}
```

Upon inspecting the symbol table, the original (broken) way shows this:

```
000000000000059a T _Z4funcv
```

whereas the second method (correctly defined) shows this:

```
000000000000059a T _ZN4util4funcEv
```

Comment: Think about it: with the (bad practice) `using` approach, how would the compiler know that you're trying to define `util::func` as opposed to `::func`?

Comment: Another alternative is to change the func definition to `int util::func() { return 42; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.cpp` file, a code like that:

```
using namespace util;

void f() { }
```

Does two things:

- Makes symbols from namespace `util` visible
- Defines function `f()` in global namespace

On the other hand,

```
namespace util {
    void f() { }
}
```

Defines function `f()` in namespace util.

As a result, the first version leaves `util::f` undefined, and thus you end up with linking errors.

Comment: Ah of course, the `using` directive is only good for name _lookup_ not definition. Makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of using `namespace util {...}` **exports** the symbol from the compilation unit `util.cpp` whereas `using namespace util;` just tells the compiler to look up names in that namespace.

Edit: In the former, you basically defined the function in a global namespace `::func()`.

Further on the difference between global and anonymous (unnamed) namespace.

```
// file.cc
namespace {
int func() {}
}  // namespace
```

will only be visible within this compilation unit (internal linkage) as opposed to global visibility (external linkage) as in

```
// file.cc
int func() {}
```

Comment: It is not anonymous namespace. It is global namespace.